# Fragments and lists

Tags: android

Hi I'm new on android I have a task to implements app using three fragment when select frag 1 a custom list of name and images appear when select 2 a list of names and images and add or delete button the third show a gridview of places with there names

Comment: This is not the site where you tell us what you want. This is the site where you post the problem you are having and we try and fix it for you.

Comment: Are you expecting that someone will post your task as a answer? Please try to google before writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use tabbed fragments and start with the tutorial here:

http://inducesmile.com/android/android-tab-with-swipe-views-viewpager-fragmentpageradapter-in-android-studio/

Hope this helps, it helped me enormously.

Comment: And...to be perfectly honest, I have never had anyone 'try and fix' a problem for me on this site. Sadly, many are very quick to post negative comments or in my case say they are confused by the perfectly clear question. So I decided I would actually try and help someone as is the point of the site. Please vote my answer up if it actually helps you.